# How to share a dependency (jar) between 2 wars in JBoss

Tags: maven, jar, jboss, manifest, war

I have 2 war's (say, A and B) and 1 jar (C).

Both A.war and B.war depend on the jar C. Since jar C contains singletons, there can only be 1 C, shared for A and B.

I build every deployment with maven without any problems. Both the pom from A and B contain:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>C</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to add the deployments to JBoss (manually, through the management console), C and A give me no problems, but B throws errors:

```
outcome 'failed', "JBAS014671: Failed services". 
StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./b: Failed to start service 
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: failed to link [class from B] (Module "B.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [class from jar C]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [class from jar C] from (Module "B.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
```

So basically: JBoss can't resolve the dependency from B.war to C.jar. 
I've already added maven-war-plugin for A and B and the maven-jar-plugin for C.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.slf4j</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So basically: I want a shared project (jar) C for A and B in JBoss. I use IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5 and JBoss Wildfly 8.2.1. The lib for C cannot be added to A or B.

What am I missing/doing wrong? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you include the jar file in both war files?  In most cases this isn't any worse than using a shared jar.

The standard way to do this is to package both .war files and the .jar file into a single .ear file deployment. This way they all get deployed together.

Alternatively, if you are using JBOSS AS 7.1+ or Wildfly you could build the jar into a module and install it in the server itself.

Comment: I did that at first, but C contains singletons with a cache, and that would result in two caches at the same time (one for A and one for B). So there can only be one instance of C (also memory-wise). Is there a possibility to keep the URL-mappings in .ear files? Because in the future i will have another front-end war depending on C. (So 1 webservice, 2 front-end's and one core). I'll have a look at the module's in jboss.